# Elementwise if elif function in python using arrays

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, numpy, definition

I have a definition

```
def myfunc(a, b):
    if a < (b*10):
        result = a*2
    else:
        result = a*(-1)
    return result
```

Now this obviously works perfectly when I feed in my `a` and `b` values one by one using for loops, however it takes forever (I've simplified the definition a wee bit) and I know from experience that passing in the values as an array will speed it up.

So how do I modify this code to accept arrays. I've used the `any()` and `all()` commands but I must be using them wrong as my function only spits out one value rather than an array of values.

An example of my desired output would be:

```
>>>a = np.array([1,5,50,500])
>>>b = 1
>>>print myfunc(a, b)
array([-1, -5, 100, 1000])
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
def myfunc(a, b):
    return np.where(a < b*10, a*2, -a)
```

For example,

```
In [48]: a = np.array([1, 5, 50, 500])

In [49]: b = 1

In [50]: myfunc(a, b)
Out[50]: array([   2,   10,  -50, -500])
```

Note the output is not the same as your desired output, but is consistent with the code you posted. You can of course get the desired output by reversing the inequality:

```
def myfunc(a, b):
    return np.where(a > b*10, a*2, -a)
```

then

```
In [52]: myfunc(a, b)
Out[52]: array([  -1,   -5,  100, 1000])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Although this does work, there was another comment that simply used np.all(a < (b*10)) with my existing definition; why should I use np.where instead of np.all?...edit-ooops it seems I did put the inequality the wrong way around, fortunately this didn't create confusion to my question :)

Comment: `np.all` returns a single boolean value, `True` or `False`. It simply tests if each and every element of `a` (and corresponding element of `b`) satisfies `a < b*10`. (It returns `True` if the condition is true element-wise, otherwise it returns `False`). I don't think that helps you in this situation.

Comment: Great answer! I wasn't aware you can use `np.where` with the additional two arguments, I will definitely be using this much more often

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
myarray = [1, 5, 50, 500]
b = 1
[myfunc(a, b) for a in myarray]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is simple enough that it can be dropped entirely:

```
arr = [1, 5, 50, 500]
arr = [a * 2 if a < b * 10 else -a for a in arr]
```

Comment: But I expect the list comp to be significantly slower than the numpy array operations.

Comment: @mgilson: Absolutely. I just have no numpy experience